# Simple sign token mechanism with RSA in .NET

Tags: .net, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to build a simple auth mechanism to authorize or deny calls to a specific endpoint on my microservice app.

The idea is that only certain calls from a microservice X to Y can be allowed, to do so I want to generate an RSA key pair and use the private key to encrypt the token and let the microservice use the public one to decrypt it once received.

To achieve this, I built a JSON token with two fields: issuer and expire time.

Then I sign the token with the private key:

```
using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportFromPem(PrivateKey);

    var token = AuthMaintenanceToken.CreateToken();//the json string token
    byte[] encodedToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token);

    byte[] encryptedToken = rsa.SignData(encodedToken, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedToken);
}
```

Then I send the token as a header "xyx" in the http request to the microservice.

Now on the endpoint , I get the token from the http header and I have to "decrypt" it and check its fields.

How can I achieve this? I sense that I'm not on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your data like this:

```json
{
    "authData":{ 
        "issuer": "mywebsite.com",
        "expTime": 01/01/2023
     },
    "signature":"Your signature"
}
```

After that, you can take only authData, sign it and put a result to signature field. This JSON can be encoded as base64, and put to HTTP header.

The destination service gets a HTTP request:

1. Read HTTP auth header with your data
2. Read authData
3. Read signature and check it by public key. If it's a same(like authData), so the request could be sent to next stage.

To implement the verification you can use

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Also you can check this article about RSA

- https://sjm.io/blog/rsa-file-signing/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You need to understand the [difference](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/122055/275392) between Encryption and Digital Signing.

> to do so I want to generate an RSA key pair and use the private key to
> encrypt the token and let the ms use the public one to decrypt it once
> received.

Digital signing is one way, You won't be able to retrieve the original data once signed, This is Mainly used for [non-repudiation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/ja/b2badv-communication/1.0.0?topic=concepts-nonrepudiation-overview). I believe you are seeking to use encryption as you want to retrieve the original data that was encrypted.

**Side note**:
In Encryption, The Public key is used for Encryption and
Private key is used for Decryption

So here's how I would  encrypt and decrypt this token.

```
using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportFromPem(privateKey);
    // Encrypt and decrypt a message
    var token = "TOKEN";
    var encryptedToken= Encryptor.EncryptMessage(token, rsa);
    var decryptedToken = Encryptor.DecryptMessage(encryptedToken, rsa);

    Console.WriteLine("Original token: " + token);
    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted token: " + Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedToken));
    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted token: " + decryptedToken);
}
```

`Encryptor.cs`

```
public static class Encryptor
 {
     public static byte[] EncryptMessage(string message, RSA rsa)
     {
         byte[] encodedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
         byte[] encryptedMessage = rsa.Encrypt(encodedMessage, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);

         return encryptedMessage;
     }

     public static string DecryptMessage(byte[] encryptedMessage, RSA rsa)
     {
         byte[] decryptedMessage = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedMessage, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
         string originalMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedMessage);

         return originalMessage;
     }
    
 }
```